# How do I turn off the steam controller start and end sound?

Tags: steam, controllers

I thought that this would be a pretty simple setting, but somehow I couldn't find it.
When you turn the steam controller on, it plays a short sound. The same happens when you turn it off. I know where you can change these sounds, but it does not seem possible to just deactivate those sounds.

How do I do that? Alternatively, how do I reduce the volume?

Comment: There seem to be options in the big picture controller settings, but the setting to dim the light only worked on my PC for me; connected to my link it is bright as ever... :-(